# Custom Controls for HTML5 Videos don't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am customising a video in html and css. So far the play button works and the full screen mode works too. But if I try to drag the slider (the one next to PLAY button) it is meant to change the position in the video too. Same with the volume button (next to MUTE button) - it doesn’t work if I try to slide it.

I wonder what is wrong with my code as I was partially following a tutorial and that’s the way they used for the tutorial.

```
 <div id="video-container">
<!-- Video -->
<video id="video-container__video" width="640" height="365">
  <source src='_assets/media/big_buck_bunny.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
</video>
<!-- Video Controls -->
<div id="video-controls">
  <button type="button" id="video-controls__play-pause">Play</button>
  <input type="range" id="video-controls__seek-bar" value="0">
  <button type="button" id="video-controls__mute">Mute</button>
  <input type="range" id="video-controls__volume-bar" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="1">
  <button type="button" id="video-controls__full-screen">Full-Screen</button>
</div>
```

```
window.onload = function() {
//video
var video = document.getElementById("video-container__video");
//Buttons 
var playButton = document.getElementById("video-controls__play-pause");
var muteButton = document.getElementById("video-controls__mute");
var fullScreenButton = document.getElementById("video-controls__full-screen");

//sliders
var seekBar = document.getElementById("video-controls__seek-bar");
var volumeBar = document.getElementById("video-controls__volume-bar");

//event listener for the play and pause button

playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (video.paused == true) {
        video.play();

    //button text will change to Pause
    playButton.innerHTML = "Pause";
    } else {
    //pause the video

    video.pause();

    //button will update its text to play
    playButton.innerHTML = "Play";
    }
});

// Event listener for the full-screen button
fullScreenButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (video.requestFullscreen) {
    video.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (video.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    video.mozRequestFullScreen(); // Firefox
    } else if (video.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    video.webkitRequestFullscreen(); // Chrome and Safari
    }
});



//event listener for the change bar 
seekBar.addEventListener("change", function() {
    //calculate the new time 
    var time = video.duration * (seekBar.value / 100);

    //update the video time 
    video.currentTime = time;
});
//the change bar will move as the video plays
video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
    //Calculate the slider value
    var value = (100 / video.duration) * video.currentTime;

    //Update the slider value
    seekBar.value = value;
})

//pause the video when the slider handle is being  dragged 
seekBar.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
    video.pause();
});

//play the video when the 
seekBar.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
    video.play();
});

volumeBar.addEventListener("change", function() {
    //update the video volume
    video.volume = volumeBar.value;
});

}
```

Comment: Just a thought - are you sure the video has downloaded in it's entirety before you interact with the slider? If the video is still downloading in the background, that may throw off the expected behavior of the slider?

Comment: @paula I just tested your code and it works flawlessly. Maybe you're just irritated because you have to release the mouse button before a change will take effect.

Comment: @obscure weird, I tested on several browsers and the issue is still the same :(

Comment: Indeed @paula - what exactly ain't working? The volume doesn't change? The slider doesn't move? Do you see any error messages in the debug console (F12)?

Comment: @obscure the volume works but the slider doesn't change - if I try to move it it goes back to the start